# Executing C# win form apps in linux machine

Tags: linux, winforms

How to execute Windows Forms Application in Linux 5.0. I installed mono 2.8 on my linux machine. Here i am very new.Please help me. For console application of C#, it is executed successfully. But C# windows application it is not executed. Can u tell me what is the pre requisite condition for executing the C# windows application on Linux machine. Please.......

Comment: I'm sure that you get some error messages somewhere when trying to execute the winforms application. How about you post those errors here.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Mono guide to porting Winforms applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can without running it in wine or something like that.

You can code in .net but i think the front end still needs to be in GTK or linux UI equivalent

Comment: I installed mono 2.8 runtime for executing the C# code in Linux. But only console app is worlking, when i execute C# win apps it give so many error. so tell me the pre requisite condition. and how to execute.

Comment: How have you made the app? its it a win forms app written on windows that you have opened in linux. Or was it started in linux and designed with the linux front end? I have not made an app before and I have looked at it but it appeared to me that the front end needs to be designed in linux but the code behind is usually mostly ok - you may need to change using statements to those of the GTK libraries etc

Comment: Here i written everything in windows for creating win forms and i want to run it in linux o/s and i want the same result like in windows o/s ,  so what should i do. Please ..........

Comment: If you have written it all in windows already then I think your only option would be to run it in an emulator like 'Wine'. otherwise you will need to abstract your business logic to a .net assembly and re write the front end in linux. There is some information on this site that may help http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:_Porting_Winforms_Applications